# Reporting chi-squared test with unequal sample sizes in APA format

Tags: chi-squared-test, sample-size

Reporting chi-squared test results in APA format requires reporting N, the sample size. If I am comparing proportions from two different samples, how should I report N?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first sample, you had $N_1$ observation, of which a certain number were in each category.

In the second sample, you had $N_2$ observations, of which a certain number were in each category.

Those “certain” numbers are what go in your contingency table to perform the test. The the $N$ you report is $N=N_1+N_2$.